# how to insert user given values into a given array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
//given array in main class
 
class Program
    
{

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 10, 20, 12};
            BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
            
            //what I want to do
            bt.insertElement(45);

        }

   }

// don't mind that the class says binarytree I just want to know how to insert a number in an array

public class BinaryTree

{
   
    public void insertElement(int num)
     {

        //not sure how to go about it

     }

}
```

Comment: You cant insert element to an array. Why dont you use just List<T>? If you have to or want to use array, you should create a list from existing array then add new element to List then convert it back to array. But why do you even need this?

Comment: it's part of my assignment where my teacher wants it where a user can insert a new value into an array then use the numbers of that array to insert that into a binary tree then print out the values using in-order traversal

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 10, 20, 12 };

        insertElement(ref nums, 45);

    }

    public static void insertElement(ref  int[] nums, int num)
    {
        var temp = nums.ToList();
        temp.Add(45);
        nums = temp.ToArray();
        }
}
```